# Clarification for bijection between two infinite sets

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, infinity

I am looking at [the proof of infinite set being equivalent to its proper subset](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Infinite_Set_is_Equivalent_to_Proper_Subset/Proof_1).

In a part of proof 1, we have:
$$S \cup (T \setminus S)= T$$
and
$$S_{1} \cup (T \setminus S) = T \setminus  S_{2}$$
I understand this part; however I have difficulty to see there is a bijection between $T$ and $T \setminus S_{2}$. It makes sense, but I am not sure why is that true.

Comment: yes I can see that. Maybe a better way of asking my question is, if there is bijection between $A$ and $B$ and we have $A \cup (U \backslash A) = U$ and $B \cup (U \backslash A) = U \backslash (A \backslash B)$, why should be a bijection between $U$ and  $U \backslash (A \backslash B)$?

Comment: I did not look at this problem in this way at first, but this is exactly what bothers me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have established that there is a bijection $f$ from $S$ to $S_1$.
Now, $T \smallsetminus S$ is disjoint with $S$ and hence with $S_1$ (since $S_1 \subseteq S$), i.e. $S \cap (T \smallsetminus S) = \emptyset = S_1 \cap (T \smallsetminus S)$.
This means that the following function $h \colon S \cup (T \smallsetminus S) \to S_1 \cup (T \smallsetminus S)$ defined by:
\begin{align}
 h(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f(x) & \text{if } x \in S \\
x & \text{otherwise (i.e. if }x \in T \smallsetminus S\text{)}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
is well-defined and is actually a bijection (since the "$f$ part" of $h$ is a bijection and the "identity part of $h$ is a bijection, and the two parts do not "overlap" and "cover" all the domain and codomain of $h$).

Finally, it turns out that $S \cup (T \smallsetminus S) = T$ and $S_1 \cup (T \smallsetminus S) = T \smallsetminus S_2$, thus $h$ is indeed a bijection from $T$ to $T \smallsetminus S_2$.

Comment: just to clarify, do you mean $f(x_{n})=x_{2n-1}$? Function $f$ was defined later in that proof and I do not think you are referring to that.

Comment: @Rob - Yes, sorry. The bijection $f \colon S \to S_1$ I refer to is the one such that $f(x_n) = x_{2n-1}$.